# Facebook page -> feed/posts/statuses: how to treat the data?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I'm accessing a client's FB page to fill a feed on his website.
I am accessing it with PHP and Curl that way:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/pageName/feed?access_token=tokenValue");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101206 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.13'); // set the user agent here

$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

2 questions here:

- whether I use the feed, the posts or the statuses parameters I get a lot of information. Is there not a way to access only the posts IDs, titles and their short description...?
- How to sort out and use the returned array? I get an ugly array that's suppose to be an stdClass, but I can't access it simply... it's not json, not xml, ... what is it?? maybe someone knows a good library to handle this...?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the returned data. It may be JSON or XML; so there wouldn't be a definitive answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1. Yes you can. Append the fields you want (comma separated) to the **fields** parameter like so:

https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor/feed?fields=id,message,picture&access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAGtey9egGaeFXS3AqtRx8LUITiIZA92Lfqlt3Es5wCEWnsrg9yroFwngYD9GrrDtbZBnDeAHN3ffWAKMVZAVbc89lIrZCgZDZD

Question 2: Decode the returned data, which is json like so:

```
$data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
```

Comment: Note, I put the url as a link so that you can see the data returned. Obviously you'll need to put this in your 'curl_setopt' call.

Comment: One more question, the access token I asked my client to generate yesterday seems to have expired today... is this a normal behaviour? Is there a way to implement a "long-term" solution to access a FB page posts/feed...?

Comment: This is normal. If the user has still authorised your app - then you can request another token. If you want a token that never expires, unless the user changes their password - then you must request the 'offline_access' permission.